# Spring Security maxSession doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

I want  to prevent login when user exceed maxSession count. For example every user can login once. And then if logged user try another login system should disable login for him.

```
.sessionManagement()
.maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expire").maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
.sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());


@Bean
public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**NOTE**: This is tested on *Spring MVC* and *4.3.9.RELEASE*, I haven't used Spring Boot yet.

I found a solution, let me share how it worked with me.

1)  I configured HttpSecurity with SessionManagement as following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()        // 1
      .antMatchers(...)
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
    .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .permitAll()
      .and()
    .logout()
      .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
      .permitAll()
      .and()
    .sessionManagement()                          // 2
      .maximumSessions(1)                         // 3
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)          // 4
        .expiredUrl("/login?expired")             // 5
        .sessionRegistry(getSessionRegistry())    // 6
    ;           
}
```

With the help of the doc [Spring Doc > HttpSecurity > sessionManagement()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#sessionManagement--)

> Example Configuration
>
> The following configuration demonstrates how to enforce that only a
>   single instance of a user is authenticated at a time. If a user
>   authenticates with the username "user" without logging out and an
>   attempt to authenticate with "user" is made the first session will be
>   forcibly terminated and sent to the "/login?expired" URL.
>
> ```
> @Configuration  
> @EnableWebSecurity  
> public class SessionManagementSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>     @Override
>     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>             http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and().formLogin()
>                             .permitAll().and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)
>                             .expiredUrl("/login?expired");
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
>             auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
>     }  }
> ```
>
> When using SessionManagementConfigurer.maximumSessions(int), do not forget to
>   configure HttpSessionEventPublisher for the application to ensure that
>   expired sessions are cleaned up. In a web.xml this can be configured
>   using the following:
>
> ```
> <listener>
>       <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
>  </listener>
> ```
>
> Alternatively,
>   AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.enableHttpSessionEventPublisher()
>   could return true.

We could know why we need `sessionManagement()`, `maximumSessions(1)`, and of course `expiredUrl("/login?expired")`.

- So why the need of `antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()`?
  So that you could have permission to be redirect to `/login?expired`, otherwise you will be redirect to `/login` because `anyRequest().authenticated()`, with current `HttpSecurity` configuration `permitAll()` is applied to `/login` and `/login?logout`.

2) If you actually need to access current logged in user or `expireNow()` specific session for specific user like me, you might need `getSessionRegistry()`, but without it `maximumSessions(1)` works fine.

So again with the help of the doc:

> When using SessionManagementConfigurer.maximumSessions(int), do not forget to
>   configure HttpSessionEventPublisher for the application to ensure that
>   expired sessions are cleaned up. In a web.xml this can be configured
>   using the following:
>
> ```
> <listener>
>       <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
>  </listener>
> ```
>
> Alternatively,
>   AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.enableHttpSessionEventPublisher()
>   could return true.

So I should change my override `enableHttpSessionEventPublisher()` in my `SecurityWebInitializer.java` class:

```
public class SecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected boolean enableHttpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

3) Now just one last thing that I found **it was my issue**:
  As I am new in Spring framework, I learned to do custom UserDetails but with a little not good implementation, but I might do better later, I created an Entity that acts as both an `Entity` and a `UserDetails`:

```
    @Entity
    @Component("user")
    public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // ...

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof User) {
              return username.equals( ((User) obj).getUsername() );
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0;
        }
    }
```

I found some one recommended years ago in the forum [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/99166-maximum-sessions-1-does-not-work?p=545061#post545061), that you should implement both `hashCode()` `equals()` methods, and if you take look at the source code of the default implementation for UserDetails [`User.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java) you will find that it has both methods implemented, I did it and it worked like a charm.

So that's it, hope this helpful.

You might want to read this link too: [Spring - Expiring all Sessions of a User](https://mtyurt.net/2015/10/27/spring-expiring-all-sessions-of-a-user/)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and it was originated in my UserDetails implementation:

ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy Line 93:

```
final List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(
        authentication.getPrincipal(), false);
```

SessionRegistryImpl Line 64:

```
final Set<String> sessionsUsedByPrincipal = principals.get(principal);

if (sessionsUsedByPrincipal == null) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

In the session registry searches inside the "principals" list for a UserDetails object. So you need to override `equals` and `hashcode` in your UserDetails implementation, otherwise, it will view them as separate objects and thus always return an emptyList.

Example:

```
public class ApplicationUser implements UserDetails {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ApplicationUser)) return false;
        ApplicationUser that = (ApplicationUser) o;
        return username.equals(that.username) &&
                email.equals(that.email) &&
                password.equals(that.password);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(username, email, password);
    }

}
```

Comment: good solution that worked for me. Thanks!
The "hashCode" requirement should be more clear in many example and docs :(

Answer (score 2):

I used a custom AuthenticationFilter in Spring security 4.2.3 and this is my solution (according to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions))

Also, I had similar problem as @Chris Avraam explained, and I had to rewrite my equals() and hashCode()

```
    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        ArrayList<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> sessionAuthenticationStrategies =
                Lists.newArrayList(new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry()),
                new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry()));
        return new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategies);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationAuthenticationFilter applicationAuthenticationFilter() throws IOException {
        ApplicationAuthenticationFilter applicationAuthenticationFilter = new ApplicationAuthenticationFilter();
        ...
        applicationAuthenticationFilter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy());
        return applicationAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                .and().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    }
```