# Concurrent session management not working. I have followed the documentation, but I think I am missing some small thing

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, spring-security, concurrency

This is my Security config

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/assets/**", "/register/**", "/","/login**")
            .permitAll().antMatchers("/profile/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_1").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_2").anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).expiredUrl("/login?expired")
            .and().and().logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true)           
            .and().csrf().disable();
    // .failureUrl("/fail");
}
```

This is to add HttpSessionEventPublisher into app context

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}
```

Please let me know what I am missing. I am still able to login from two browsers using same credentials.

Comment: Did you check this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-concurrent-sessions maybe the problem is `error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"`

Comment: Yes.I saw that. I thought this does the same - maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It is to override equals and hashCode methods of my User class which implements UserDetails based on below solutions. Comparison of UserDetails objects for authenticated principals is how session concurrency is controlled / measured

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/99166-maximum-sessions-1-does-not-work

[Spring Security maxSession doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892563/spring-security-maxsession-doesnt-work)