# Spring Boot custom implementation of UserDetails

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-session

I am trying to settup session management for spring boot 2 with spring security, and i have custoom class with implements UserDetails interface, as i know from documentation i need ovveride methods: equals and hashcode

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    SimpleUser that = (SimpleUser) o;
    return email.equals(that.email) &&
            getPassword().equals(that.getPassword());
}
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(email, getPassword());
}
```

Security Settings:

```
http.anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterAt(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

This is what i did and session management not working, i am able to do login at one computer from two different browsers, and i do not know what i am doing wrong, help me please!

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892563/spring-security-maxsession-doesnt-work?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons, why anything is not working as expected.

May be you could dig further into this by:

1. Check your `pom.xml` or your manual version management for Spring Boot and -Security version clashes
2. Follow the [very good example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) on spring.io which is build around the `spring-boot-starter-security`
3. Stick to the framework as long as possible before manually add any code. This applies especially on implementing the `equals` and `hashCode` methods you mentioned above.