# Not able to prevent multiple concurrent login from the same user in spring security with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**
Here I have edited my code as to see that i'm currently using in memory authentication for this  purpose

Here is my Security configuration file, What I want to achieve  is for one user to not have concurrent sessions.
With this code I can login with same user on multiple tabs.
Eventhough the user has an active session
Can anyone help me with this.I'm a newbie at Spring security
Thanks in Advance**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(username).password(password).roles("OPERATIONAL");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(sysUsername).password(sysPassword).roles("OPERATIONAL");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/initialPage").and().ignoring().antMatchers("/WEB-INF/**").and().ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/sp/processRequest").antMatchers("/WEB-INF/**").and().ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/sp/rest/getChannelCodeOnMID").antMatchers("/createRazorpayOrder").and().ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/createRazorpayOrder").antMatchers("/sp/rest/getNonPreferredEntities").and().ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/sp/rest/getNonPreferredEntities").antMatchers("/sp/rest/getChargesDetailsOnChannel")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/sp/rest/getChargesDetailsOnChannel").antMatchers("/paymentResponse")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/paymentResponse").antMatchers("/RedirectpaymentResponse").and()
                .ignoring().antMatchers("/RedirectpaymentResponse").and().ignoring().antMatchers("/testMerchantPage")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/sp/rest/generateChecksum").and().ignoring().antMatchers("/pushResponse")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/sp/rest/getServiceDetails")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/errorPage")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/getResponse")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/img/qrcode/**")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/sp/rest/getCancelRequest")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/sp/rest/checkTxnStatusOnOrderId")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/pushResponse")
                .and().ignoring().antMatchers("/paymentStatusApi");
        
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("**/login")).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**/api/v1/getPricingDtls").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/merchantCreationOrView").hasRole("OPERATIONAL").and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/merchantCreation").hasRole("OPERATIONAL")
        .antMatchers("/merchantView").hasRole("OPERATIONAL")
        .antMatchers("/merchantRenderedView").hasRole("OPERATIONAL")
        .antMatchers("/viewMerchantDetails").hasRole("OPERATIONAL")
        .antMatchers("/saveMerchantDetails").hasRole("OPERATIONAL")
        .antMatchers("/download").hasRole("OPERATIONAL")
        .antMatchers("/downloadSettlement").hasRole("OPERATIONAL")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").
        defaultSuccessUrl("/merchantCreationOrView",true).failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
        .and()
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
          .maximumSessions(1)
          .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).
          sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
          ;
    }

    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {         
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
    @Bean
    public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() { //(5)
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        
        return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }
    

    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple check can help you reach similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892563/spring-security-maxsession-doesnt-work) here.

Most likely you didn't implement/override correct `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your logined `User` class.

You have to do something like this, depend how logically you determine the so-called "same" user:

```
 public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof User) {
          return username.equals( ((User) obj).getUsername() );
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi  @Sam YC,Thank you for your reply , I have edited my question currently with the complete code snippet, I dont use a custom implementation of UserDetailsService .I am useing the InMemoryAuthethication for this purpose

Comment: @AnkushTiwari I see you have added this `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)`, your previous example also have this? If you remove this, does it work?

Comment: Does not work even after removing sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)

Comment: Basically your config looks fine, what you can do next: 1) remove `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)`  2) add in `.expiredUrl("/auth/login")` 3) check your `CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.html 4) for debugging, iterate through Session Registry to print out the sessions to see what's wrong https://mtyurt.net/post/spring-expiring-all-sessions-of-a-user.html

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helps.